# Is there a universal property of $\text{Spec}(-)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

I've heard it been said that the construction of Spec$R$ is a *canonical way* of taking the ring $A$ and producing a locally ringed space with $A$ as the ring of global sections. This is certainly informal; but is it correct in some technical sense? If it was, we might expect to find $\text{Spec}(-):\text{Ring}^{op}\to\text{LRSpace}$ (or indeed $\text{Spec}(A)$) characterized by some universal property. So I wonder: is this so?

Sincerely, Eivind

Comment: Isn't the thing you're looking for simply the [anti-equivalence between affine schemes and commutative rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(mathematics)#The_category_of_schemes), so it's hardly possible to get "more canonical"? If you don't want to restrict to affine schemes you still get an adjoint pair, so you have a universal property "for free".

Comment: I knew about that, but I'm thinking about $\text{Spec}$ as a functor $\text{Ring}^{op}\to\text{LRSpaces}$. This question may still be silly though :)

Comment: I clarified this assumption in the OP.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The natural bijection
$$
\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{LRS}}(X, \mathrm{Spec}(A)) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{CRing}}(A,\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X))
$$
might be the universal property of $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ you are looking for. Here $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ denotes a locally ringed space which is not necessarily a scheme.

Comment: In other words, there is a contravariant right adjunction between $\mathrm{Spec}\colon \mathcal{R}ing^{op}\to LRS$  and $\Gamma\colon LRS^{op}\to\mathcal{R}ing$ (global sections)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Does this still work if we look at all (not necessarily local) ringed spaces?

Comment: @OscarCunningham: No, because you don't get the appropriate adjunction if you enlarge one category but not the other.