# If $f: X \to \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is a morphism of schemes, and $U \cong \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is an open affine of $X$, how is $A$ an $R$-algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

I'm reading a [proof](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01KP) that starts:

> **Proof:** Assume $f$ separated. Suppose $(U,V)$ is a pair as in (1). Let $W=\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ be an affine open {subset ?} of $S$ containing both $f(U)$ and $f(V)$. Write $U=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ and $V=\operatorname{Spec}(B)$ for $R$-algebras $A$ and $B$.

---

But anyhow, I don't see how $A$ is an $R$-algebra which leads to my more general question:

**If $f: X \to \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is a morphism of schemes, and $U \cong \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is an open affine of $X$, how is $A$ an $R$-algebra?**

Comment: By the [universal property of $\mathrm{Spec}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/41352/682781), given $f$ you have that $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is an $R$-algebra. Composing with the restriction map from $X$ to $U$ you get the answer.

Comment: @Aurelio By restriction map from $X$ to $U$, do you mean the inclusion $U \hookrightarrow X$? So, basically just restrict $f$ to $U$?

Comment: I take the opportunity to point out that this is precisely why we often work in the category $\mathrm{Sch}/B$ of scheme _over a fixed base scheme_ $B$. When $B=\mathrm{Spec}(R)$, for example $R=k$ a field, this just means that all schemes are covered by spectra of $R$-algebras. For $B$ generic, the same statement holds for a varying base ring.

Comment: I mean the restriction $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\to\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X)$, where the latter is isomorphic to $A$.

Comment: @Aurelio Ah ok I see.

Comment: @Aurelio Could we have also restricted $f|_U : U \to \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ and that would have given us a map $\mathrm{Spec}(A) \to \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ which in turn gives a ring hom $R \to A$?

Comment: Yes, of course! Thar argument works too. If you write down the final $R$-action on $A$, you will see that the two approaches are basically the same.

Comment: @Aurelio Please consider compiling your comments in to an answer below :)

Comment: I'm surprised that a 10k+ rep user has not yet learned that using images for significant portions of your post is a bad idea!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following @KReiser's suggestion, I bundle my comments above into a proper answer.
Given a morphism $\DeclareMathOperator{Spec}{Spec}f:X\to \Spec R$, we obtain a map on global sections $f^\sharp\colon R\to \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$, hence the latter ring is an $R$-algebra on the nose. Moreover, by the [universal property of $\Spec$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41348/is-there-a-universal-property-of-textspec/41352#41352), there is a natural bijection between $R$-algebra structures on $\Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X)$ and morphisms $X\to \Spec R$.

This construction localises easily. For any open subset $U\subseteq X$, the restriction map $\Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X)\to\Gamma(U,\mathcal O_X)$ presents the ring of sections over $U$ as an $R$-algebra. In particular, when $U=\Spec A$, this holds for $A\simeq \Gamma(U,\mathcal O_X)$. Equivalently, we could simply consider the restriction $f_{\vert U}\colon U \to \Spec R$ and apply the universal property.

This discussion shows why we often work in the category $\mathrm{Sch}/B$ of schemes *over* a fixed scheme $B$, also called "$B$-schemes": they are schemes with a given morphism $X\to B$, and morphisms of $B$-schemes preserve the map to the base.

Consider for starters $B=\Spec R$ affine, for example $R=k$ a field: we are saying that a $B$-scheme is covered by spectra of $R$-algebras, not just rings. Similarly, a map between affine $B$-schemes is equivalent to a map of $R$-algebras.
Now look at $X\to B$, when $B$ is not necessarily affine. We pull back an affine cover $\{\Spec A_i\}$ of $B$ to $X$, and up to refining we obtain that $X$ is covered by algebras over different rings $\{A_i\}$.